# primeng calendar show time - cannot pick the initial current time

Tags: angular, primeng

When I use show time only:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="toTime[col.field]" [showTime]="showTime" [hourFormat]="24"
[timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>
```

I click on the field to set the time.
if I want the current time (initial value), I see it in the field but it's not possible to choose it. 
I need to reduce/increase a value and do the opposite operation to have the current value chosen in the field.

is there a better way to select the initial current value?
Thanks,
Tali

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an Input called defaultDate which should contain the string date.
You will run into issues with converting time back and forward from string to Date object to make it show the local time

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="toTime[col.field]" 
            [showTime]="showTime" [hourFormat]="24"
            [timeOnly]="true"
            [defaultDate]="yourTimeValueHere">
</p-calendar>
```